# Les nuances du concept de la vérité : comment traduire « правда » et « истина » le plus simplement ?

Tags: sens, traduction, choix-de-mot, synonymes, philosophie

En russe, il y a deux façons de parler de la vérité : *pravda* et *istina*. L'une, c'est la vérité « instinctive », l'autre, c'est la vérité « formelle », celle « dans les choses, hors de nous ». Dans tous les deux cas il s'agit d'idées que le monde approuve de quelque manière (qui conforment à la réalité) ; donc, la différence est seulement dans leur traitement.

Je voudrais connaître comment peut-on traduire ces mots en français le plus concisement possible s'il faut se rendre compte de cette différence du placement. La distinction n'est pas essentielle la plupart du temps, mais parfois elle est très importante, et je crois que cette importance n'est seulement pas une bizarrerie de la langue russe.

Par exemple :

1) si quelqu'un me suggère qu'il va me parler de moi-même (comment est-il bien de vivre la vie) et me promet de dire « toute la vérité » à propos de quelque aspect, ma réaction peut dépendre du mot. Il faut gagner un certain nivau de l'intimité pour dire *pravda* ; mais si un ami insiste qu'il va dire toute l'*istina*, ça peut vouloir dire qu'il est un peu ennuyante, qu'il fait beaucoup d'attention aux choses pas si importantes et/ou déjà claires ; ce n'est qu'une tendance ou une nuance, mais ça marche ;

2) en mathématiques, en logique, en programmation on dit prèsque toujours *istina* ; on peut dire *pravda*, mais c'est un peu comme un manuel pour les enfants (mais mignon);

3) le mot *pravda* a une connexion étymologique avec les règles et avec la justice : c'est ce qui est correct à faire ; « *pravda* est à nous » (правда на нашей стороне) veut dire que c'est nous qui font comme il faut, pas nos adversaires ; si on utilise *istina*, ça veut dire que nous savons quelque chose, et nos adversaires non ;

4) il y a ceux qui disent que « мне правда дороже, чем истина » (« la *pravda* est plus imporante que l'*istina* ») ; cette manière de dire leur sert à indiquer l'importance du nuyau personnel ;

5) dans une conversation, si on m'a raconté quelque chose, j'utilise le mot *pravda* pour demander si on m'a dit la vérité ; le mot *istina* serait trop philosophique ou solennel pour le contexte ; donc, le nom du journal communiste méconnu, *La Pravda*.

En deux mots, la différence recherchée se base sur  « qu'est-ce qui est vrai » (dans la nature fondamentale) vs. « comment penser » (internalement, selon mes règles).

Je cherche à réconnaître une *istina* d'après ce que le monde fait lorsque je fais quelque chose, pas d'après ce qui est correct pour moi; c'est-à-dire, si j'agis en croyant justement que quelque proposition est une *istina*, le monde récompense mes efforts ; c'est différent pour une *pravda* que je juge avant de toute récompense.

Peut-être y a-t-il quelque expression ou manière de dire pas très compliquée ? Spécialement à rendre bien le 4-ième exemple.

Merci beaucoup.

PS : j'ai une idée pour traduire le 4-ième exemple : *il faut être bien composé plutôt que correct*. Mais je ne suis pas sûr si le mot *composé* peut être attaché à la composition spirituelle... Peut-être qu'une toute autre expression rendrait mieux le sens...

Comment: Il existe ***franchise*** en français, qui peut parfois sembler suspect de la part d'un inconnu (qui serait alors perçu comme voulant trop en faire ou voulant endormir la vigilance), mais qui serait bienvenu de la part d'un familier (qui aurait acquis ce droit de prétendre à la franchise), mais ça ne semble pas correspondre à l'un ou à l'autre des concepts que vous présentez. Peut-être fais-je erreur?

Comment: Sinon, est-ce que le contraste entre ***vérité*** et ***réalité*** serait approprié? La vérité pourrait, à la rigueur, être sujette à interprétation, prendre différents visages en différents lieux, chez des peuples différents, selon des valeurs locales voire familiales, alors que la réalité est clairement objective et fixe: on ne saurait transiger avec pour la changer, elle est sous-jacente au monde que l'on connaît, à un niveau profond et immuable. Par contre, il n'y a guère à ma connaissance de contexte de familiarité avec son interlocuteur où l'une ou l'autre serait inappropriée.

Comment: 1ère: la différence que je recherche est un peu plus… philosophique. Ce sont deux façons de parler de la vérité. L'une, c'est la vérité « instinctive » (donc la connexion avec la justice, la familiarité, etc), l'autre, c'est la vérité « formelle », celle « dans les choses, hors de nous ». Par exemple, en mathématiques, c'est prèsque toujours « istina », on peut dire « pravda », mais c'est un peu comme un manuel pour les enfants (mais mignon). Je crois que ce n'est seulement pas une bizarrerie de la langue russe et que parfois il faut vraiment faire cette distinction du placement…

Comment: 2ième: Peut-être y-a-t-il des expressions complexes ? « La vérité est plus importante que la réalité »… Ça ne prend pas la nuance de la source de la vérité : c'est en nous que l'on doit trouver la composition d'esprit que permet de vivre, selon les gens qui le diraient…

Comment: Si je résume ma compréhension de vos explications, «istina» serait lié(e) à la nature fondamentale du monde (ou du sujet dont il est question), alors que «pravda» serait lié(e) à notre expérience personnelle ou commune de ce monde. Est-ce à peu près correct?

Comment: Oui! Je crois que vous m'avez compris. En fait, j'ai fait les différences entre les mots apparaître un plus évidentes qu'elles ne sont, mais je crois que j'ai expliqué la différence que je cherche: la nature fondamentale vs. nos règles internaux.

Comment: Que voulez-vous dire par «récompense» dans *“Est-ce que la récompense de ma croyance par la réalité est la chose la plus importante”*?

Comment: Si le monde hors de moi marche comme j'ai estimé et si je fais quelque chose en croyant qu'il marche comme ça, il récompense mes efforts. C'est-à-dire, je cherche à reconnaître une _istina_ d'après ce que le monde fait, pas d'après ce qui est correct pour moi.

Comment: Je suis en train de penser à une façon de récrire la question pour la faire conformer aux questions dans les commentaires…

Comment: C'est une très belle question pour moi, mais excessivement difficile. Je doute que cette subtilité de concept soit communément utilisée dans le discours français, mais je continuerai d'y réfléchir, tout en tentant de cerner convenablement les concepts russes.

Comment: Ma remarque ne répond malheureusement pas à la question, mais j'ai l'impression qu'il s'agit du même genre de nuances que nous avons en français entre les mots "justesse" et "justice". Peut-être, comme la réponse de @Montéedelait de lait le suggère, que les mots "exactitude" et "vérité" pourraient convenir ?

Comment: Est-ce que [la notion {Bouddhiste} des "Deux Vérités ou Réalités"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Deux_V%C3%A9rit%C3%A9s) capte un peu l'idée que vous cherchez?

Comment: @Trabool Oui, l'une (_istina_) est plus abstraite et moins courante que l'autre (_pravda_). Merci pour l'exemple ! À propos de l'exactitude… si on dit « c'est exact » dans une conversation, je le traduirais _eto pravda_ en russe.

Comment: @PapaPoule Curieux… En ce cas, la vérité spirituelle serait _pravda_, dans ma intuition… C'est-à-dire, _pravda_ peut être plus solennelle, elle aussi… Mais je ne sais rien du bouddhisme…

Answer (score 3):

Pour faire au plus concis, je parlerais de vérité et de Vérité (avec une majuscule, donc)
La vérité (pravda) pour tout ce qui concerne les choses usuelles et la Vérité (= istina) pour les questions d'ordre de philosophie, etc.

Cela semble très bien fonctionner pour vos exemples 3 et 5. Pour les autres, il faudra sûrement un peu expliquer la différence.

Ça ne rend pas toute la subtilité du mot, mais cela marque une nette différence et donne une valeur plus forte, plus noble, plus philosophique avec la majuscule. La différence est nette quand on emploie les deux dans une même phrase, ou seulement la forme avec majuscule. Toutefois, la forme sans majuscule employée seule risque d'englober tous les sens.

Pour marquer la différence oralement, parlez de vérité et de LA Vérité (en insistant sur le LA).

*Ce genre de traitement en français se fait par exemple avec le mot histoire. Pour distinguer une histoire (conte, récit, anecdote) de l' histoire (histoire de l'humanité, étude scientifique d'évènements historiques) on écrit "Histoire" pour désigner le second.*

*Idem avec des mots comme "homme". Quand on veut parler de l'homme dans le sens "tout être humain, l'humanité" et pas "un individu de sexe masculin", on écrit Homme.*

*Pareil avec des notions comme art, beau, justice, péché, ...*

Comment: _Ontologique_ ? Merci !